# How to get the height of a hidden absolute div

Tags: jquery, css, height, absolute

I have a div which is hidden and has absolute position and i want to get it's height so i can set it via jQuery

```
.parent2{
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100% !important;
    height: 100% !important;
}

.hidden_div{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100% !important;
    height: 100% !important;
    padding: 15px;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    overflow: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

I have tried the following without any result:

```
var div_height = $(".hidden_div").height();
var div_height = $(".hidden_div").outerHeight();
var div_height = $(".hidden_div").actual("height");
//or innerHeight or outerHeight using the plugin at https://github.com/dreamerslab/jquery.actual/
```

EDIT:

this is the layout:

```
<div class="parent1">
    <div class="parent2">
        <div class="hidden_div">

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

parent1 has no css

Comment: does `.hidden_div` have a parent element with a width set?

Comment: So height and width are `100%`can't you use parent height?

Comment: hidden div is not problem here but 100% is problem that is in percent it wouldn't get if you have parent div is not set fixed pixel height

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/QyJKA/
Problem is most likely in your parent structure.

Comment: I have edited the question with the complete structure thank you

Comment: So what? 100% of 0 is 0. parent1 has no height and no content, parent2 is 100% of 0, hidden_div is 100% of 100% of 0 = 0

Comment: I cant test it right now but if I set parent1 width and height to 100% will it display the correct height?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to fetch the `height` using jQuery.

```
alert($("div.hidden_div").css("height"));
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/YT75Z/

Comment: In this test setup, `height()` works as well. So that is not the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If possible, try removing `position:relative;` from `.parent2`

```
.parent2{
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100% !important;
    height: 100% !important;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/YT75Z/2/